# Vim/Terminal color scheme appears over SSH but not on local Mac

Tags: macos, vim, ssh, terminal, color-scheme

I use terminal on my Macbook to SSH into Linux machines in order to complete my homework for a class. I use Vim to code in C, for which I have a small set of .vimrc configurations that is the exact same on the remote (Linux) machine as well as my local (Mac) machine. None of these should affect the color scheme of terminal/Vim.

Over SSH, the C code is illustrated with a color scheme that I have come to enjoy. Here's a snippet:
[image: vim over ssh]

However, when I try to write code in the same way on my local machine instead of SSH, there are no colors at all. Here is the same code I have copied onto my local machine:
[image: vim on local]

My Mac is set to the new Catalina Dark Mode, and Terminal is on the Basic (Default) color profile. My .vimrc contains the following:

```
set linebreak
set showbreak=+++
set textwidth=100
set showmatch

set hlsearch
set smartcase
set ignorecase
set incsearch

set autoindent
set cindent
set shiftwidth=4
set smartindent
set smarttab
set softtabstop=4

set ruler

set undolevels=1000
set backspace=indent,eol,start
```

Would this be an issue with vim color schemes/config, terminal config, or perhaps something else? Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to turn on the syntax highlighting.

`:syn on`

You can set this in your `.vimrc` to avoid typing it every time.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. Coloring is *usually* achieved via syntax highlighting. The command `syntax enable` (enable works better than on) can do this
2. You can edit over ssh with vim:

```
vim scp://user@remote-host/path/to/file
```